# Tags can now be longer -- do we want to change any?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of today, [tags can be 35 characters long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/156248); the limit used to be 25.

Are there any tags that were stunted to fit into the length limit and could profit from the new limit?

Keep in mind that longer tags are not per se *better*. We should only create very long tags if they are absolutely necessary for clarity and/or removal of ambiguity.

Comment: The only one I'm aware of on CS is [tag:natural-lang-processing], and Shog's already done it.